# Is the vector space of all linear transformations finite dimensional?

Tags: linear-algebra

Okay so I want to prove $dim\ \mathcal L(V,W)=(\dim V)(\dim W)$ by showing $\mathcal L(V,W)$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Mat}(\dim W,\dim V,\mathbf F)$. The proof of $\mathcal L(V,W) \cong \operatorname{Mat}(\dim W,\dim V,\mathbf F)$ needs to assume $\mathcal L(V,W)$ being finite-dimensional, so I just wonder how on earth can I prove that?

Comment: You are probably assuming $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional, otherwise the claim is false. Under this assumption, the isomorphism with the vector space of matrices is the standard one, and does not make any dimensionality assumptions on the space of transformations.

Comment: Yeah I forget to state that...

Comment: The proof that $\mathcal L(V,W) \cong Mat(dimW,dimV,\mathbf F)$ I've seen involves proving that the linear map $M(T,(basis \ of \ V),(basis \ of \ W)$ being bijective, thus proving isomorphism. However the theorem which states two isomorphic vector spaces being of the same dimension assumes they are finite-dimensional. So I think without the assumption that $\mathcal L(V,W)$ is finite-dimensional, one cannot justify $dim \ \mathcal L(V,W) = (dimV)(dimW)$

Comment: If you have the book Linear Algebra Done Right by Axler, second edition, the theorem I refer to is 3.18, and the theorem I need to prove is 3.20

Comment: the fact that isomorphic vector spaces have the same dimension does not depend on finite dimensionality. It is a very straightforward proof. In fact, just prove that any monomorphism sends a linearly independent set to a linear independent set. That suffices for your purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $V={\rm gen}\{b_1,...,b_n\}$ and $W={\rm gen}\{c_1,...,c_m\}$ be vector spaces.
For each linear transformation $T:V\to W$ assign to each image
$$T(b_1)={T^1}_1c_1+\cdots +{T^m}_1c_m$$
$$T(b_2)={T^1}_2c_1+\cdots +{T^m}_2c_m$$
$$...$$
$$T(b_n)={T^1}_nc_1+\cdots +{T^m}_nc_m$$
their linear combination in the codomain. Then the map $T\mapsto [{T^i}_j]$ will be a isomorphism  between ${\cal L}(V,W)\to Mat_{m\times n}(
\mathbf{F})$.

Comment: I see what you are doing is to prove that $\mathcal L(V,W) \cong Mat_{m \times n} (\mathbf F)$, but from this to prove they have the same dimension requires assuming both $\mathcal L$ and $Mat(\mathbf F)$ being finite dimensional.

Comment: there are $m\times n$ basic matrices with a one in only one entry and zeros the remaining ones, they are used to define $m\times n$ elementary linear transformation needed to write as a  linear combinations any other linear transformation $T$.